# phpmyadmin can't login on nginx Centos 6 Server

Tags: nginx, centos6, php-fpm, mariadb

I've installed `phpmyadmin` on my ded server with `Nginx` and `MariaDB` under Centos 6.i can login into mariaDB cli with `root` user falwlessly but i can't login through `phpmyadmin`. it shows me first login page of `phpmyadmin` and when i  enter user and pass , page will refresh but nothings happen, only tokens add in adress . I've used static linking for make link between phpmyadmin folder and nginx root dir .i should say that other php pages load flawlessly.however any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Can you tell us how you have installed nginx and phpmyadmin : from source ? from a repo (which one) ?

Comment: yes,i've installed from `remi` and `epel` repositories , why ?

Comment: Just to try to reproduce in Lab. I'll let you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers wasn't suitable for me . however i solved that another way and i write the solution here for others :
open `phpmyadmin` configuration in a editor . in `centOS` i did this :

> nano /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php

then find this line :

```
...    
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
...
```

and change it to `http` :

```
...    
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
...
```

then recheck your `phpmyadmin` url in your site

Answer (score 2):

After dealing a few hours with the same issue, I found out that session.save_path is kinda important, so I've took a few steps to check it in an empty PHP file

1) Get the current value from ini with

`var_dump( ini_get('session.save_path') );`.

The result for me was

`string(20) "/var/lib/php/session"`

2) Now I wanted to know if my php can write in that folder so I went for

`var_dump( is_writable(  ini_get('session.save_path') ) );`

The result was false. This means that the user which controls my php-fpm cannot write that directory.

3) I went in front of that folder with

`/var/lib/php`

check his owner with

`ls -all`

The result was

`drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 Sep 17 15:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root   4096 Sep 17 15:48 ..
drwxrwx---  2 root apache 4096 Sep  3 08:07 session
drwxrwx---  2 root apache 4096 Sep  3 08:07 wsdlcache`

And here I just notice that my session folder is controlled by **apache**. But there is no apache on my server I'm runnig with nginx.

**Solution**

Make nginx to be the owner of this folder

`chown nginx session/`

Now doesn't matter what `auth_type` I use, they are both working

Answer (score 0):

For cookie authentication you'll need correct access rights to your session directory. Make sure that the directory defined in `session.save_path` php variable is writable for your web-server.

Answer (score -1):

Is PhpAdmin installed correctly?

I suggest Re installing it. If you cant Login anyway then thats the first thing to try fresh.

After you do that, change the permissions of the phpadmin directory (below is a general linux www directory, check & change for Centos if its diferrent)

```
      chmod -R 777 /var/www/phpmyadmin
```

Open a browser and start Phpadmin to see if you can log in.

If you get any errors, Post them back in your question to have a look

Comment: but the first login page loads !!!